# How to pass multiple variables from one Activity to another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How to pass multiple variables from one activity to another activity?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // get EditText by id
                EditText inputTxt_1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
                EditText inputTxt_2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                EditText inputTxt_3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
                EditText inputTxt_4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);

                // Store EditText in Variable
                String  str1 = inputTxt_1.getText().toString();
                String str2 = inputTxt_2.getText().toString();
                String str3 = inputTxt_3.getText().toString();
                String str4 = inputTxt_4.getText().toString();
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("inputTxt_1", str1);
            intent.putExtra("inputTxt_2", str2);
            intent.putExtra("inputTxt_3", str3);
            intent.putExtra("inputTxt_4", str4);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
   }
}
```

It shows cannot resolve method `putExtra`, `startActivity` and even not accepting the str1 and other etc. I am new to android. kindly help.

Comment: Move the `}` that's right above `Intent intent = ...` to after `startActivity(intent);`.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is poorly formatted so it's difficult to be sure, but I think the issue is that you're closing your `onClick` method body too soon. The `Intent` setup and `startActivity` calls are done outside the body of this method, which is the body of the instance of the anonymous `View.OnClickListener` class you've created.

Try this instead:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        // get EditText by id
        EditText inputTxt_1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
        EditText inputTxt_2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText inputTxt_3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        EditText inputTxt_4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);

        // Store EditText in Variable
        String  str1 = inputTxt_1.getText().toString();
        String str2 = inputTxt_2.getText().toString();
        String str3 = inputTxt_3.getText().toString();
        String str4 = inputTxt_4.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("inputTxt_1", str1);
        intent.putExtra("inputTxt_2", str2);
        intent.putExtra("inputTxt_3", str3);
        intent.putExtra("inputTxt_4", str4);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```